# How to get sum of field set and update row with this sum in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

if there is a table.

```
id  |total |  setcolumn
1   |  5   |  2,3,4
2   |  1   |  1,3
3   |  3   |  2,1,4
```

i need to update total column to equal sum of setcolumn like this

```
id  | total|  setcolumn
1   |  9   |  2,3,4
2   |  4   |  1,3
3   |  7   |  2,1,4
```

Comment: I think we can reject the premise of the question. We would not have such a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the meta column values by "," this way it will create differently each row and then you can use group by to add them.

Seems similar to your question here:

[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: I ask if there is one query can do this for around 3000 row

Comment: @AkramElhaddad What difference does the number of rows make. 3 or 300; it's all the same.

Comment: no problem can you write suitable query to do this ?